# Wordpress Testimonials "Uncaught Error"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've got a staging site set up for a client, where everything worked great until a recent plugin update. I can't find a way to contact the author of the plugin. I am also using the free version so I am afraid he wouldn't care one way or another anyway.

My issue is if I move the Testimonials to the bottom of the main home page, no Syntax error. If I move it above the "What we've Been Up To" section, where it should be, then that section never loads and this error comes up when I inspect the page. This Wordpress site is using the "Visual Composure" as well.

I'm not sure what code to copy and paste to show in this form, so I am going to copy some HTML. Not sure that will do ANY good.

**The staging site is:** http://staging.sportinglifebar.com/

**The Error is:** Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {'status':'Nothing found'}

**Testimonial Section Code:**
There was too much to post. Please see staging site.

**"What We've Been Up To" Section:**

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid blog_section_description_class vc_custom_1448504981863 ult-vc-hide-row vc-row-fade" data-rtl="false" data-row-effect-mobile-disable="true" data-img-parallax-mobile-disable="false" data-fadeout-percentage="55" style="position: relative; background-image: none !important;"><div class="upb_row_bg vcpb-default" data-upb_br_animation="" data-parallax_sense="30" data-bg-override="0" data-bg-animation="left-animation" data-bg-animation-type="h" data-animation-repeat="repeat" style="min-width: 1358px; left: 0px; width: 1358px; opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;http://staging.sportinglifebar.com/wp-content/uploads/wood_bg_4.png&quot;); background-attachment: scroll; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-size: cover; background-repeat: repeat;"></div><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12" style="opacity: 1;"><div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1446834908203"><div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  vc_custom_1446835247406 intro_section_description">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">Check out what we’ve been up to!</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
<!-- vc_grid start -->
<div class="vc_grid-container-wrapper vc_clearfix">
    <div class="vc_grid-container vc_clearfix wpb_content_element vc_basic_grid vc_custom_1451934074454" data-vc-grid-settings="{&quot;page_id&quot;:474,&quot;style&quot;:&quot;all&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;vc_get_vc_grid_data&quot;,&quot;animation_in&quot;:&quot;zoomIn&quot;,&quot;shortcode_id&quot;:&quot;1451935320650-ff3c3774-d210-0&quot;,&quot;tag&quot;:&quot;vc_basic_grid&quot;}" data-vc-request="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" data-vc-post-id="474" data-vc-public-nonce="ae65146011">
    <div class="vc_grid-loading"></div></div>
</div><!-- vc_grid end -->
</div></div></div></div>
```

**Error code:**
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {'status':'Nothing found'}
There was too much to post the actual code. Please see staging site.

Comment: rollback the upgrade

Comment: How do you do that with a plugin? I thought about that but couldn't figure out how to download an older version.

Comment: from your backup files

Answer (score 0):

I found the developers page and previous versions listed to download. I'm going to go this route to fix the issue.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonial-add/developers/